# DryIOC: Resolve all default registrations, leaving out keyed registrations

Tags: ioc-container, dryioc

I'm registering a bunch of different implementations of the same interface without service key, then adding

```
container.Register<IMyInterface, ImplementationA>();
container.Register<IMyInterface, ImplementationB>();
container.RegisterMany<ImplementationC>(serviceKey: "myServiceKey");

public class ImplementationA: IMyInterface
{
}

public class ImplementationB: IMyInterface
{
}

public class ImplementationC: IMyInterface, IMyInterface2
{
}
```

Now, when I call to resolve all IMyInterface instances, I get ImplementationA, ImplementationB and ImplementationC

```
var iMyInterfaceImplementations = container.ResolveMany<IMyInterface>();
Assert.Equals(iMyInterfaceImplementations.Count() == 3);
```

if I provide the serviceKey, I get just ImplementationC

```
var iMyKeyedInterfaceImplementations = container.ResolveMany<IMyInterface>(serviceKey: "myServiceKey);
Assert.Equals(iMyKeyedInterfaceImplementations.Coud() == 1);
```

Is there any way to get all the non keyed implementations? So that if I called
    container.ResolveMany(what to put here?)

I'd get ImplementationA, and ImplementationB, but Not ImplementationC.

The solution should be generic.. in the end I don't want to skip just ImplementationC but all possible registrations of IMyInterface that are not keyed. I already tried

```
container.ResolveMany<IMyInterface>(serviceKey: DefaultKey.Value);
```

but that returns me one single IMyInterface implementations, not the two I registered.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the related doc https://github.com/dadhi/DryIoc/blob/master/docs/DryIoc.Docs/RegisterResolve.md#resolving-as-keyvaluepair-wrapper

What you need is:

```
var defaultItems = container.Resolve<KeyValuePair<DefaultKey, IMyInterface>[]>();
```